Is there a 'standard' way to generate a compiler warning if a class is instantiated more than once?
I have a class which controls a set of devices. 99% of the time there will only ever be one instance of this class created but, every so often, there is a need to instantiate two copies (where two discrete sets of devices are used). The latter situation doesn't happen very often but it is needed occasionally so I can't just use a singleton pattern.
However, I would like to protect against a developer doing this accidentally by showing a warning if more than one instantiation is detected, preferably at compile time. A colleague suggested this can be achieved with C++ template metaprogramming but I can't find an example anywhere.
Fairly easy to do at runtime but compile time seems more of a challenge.

I believe it is impossible as such, because a compiler compling one translation unit cannot possibly determine if another instance is created in another translation unit.

Post code instead of description of code.

As a workaround, you could provide a singleton for the common case, and a second static method returning a new instance. This would at least force the developer to make a conscious decision to create another instance.

Let your class count the instances. Give the constructor a parameter like bool allowMultiple, and do an assertion failure or whatever you like doing when an additional instance is created without this parameter set to true.

@ChristianStieber That completely  misses the point of the question, which is about enforcement at compile time. As they state, they are aware this is "fairly easy to do at runtime".

If target is an embedded platform with memory mapped devices, you can craft ways to do it; it needs a bit of meta programming to work, but a minimum runtime cost is inevitable.

The usual way is to write a singleton class that prevents code outside the class (or its friends) from instantiating the class.    The code that actually instantiates the class is then relatively simple, so it is easy to ensure it only ever instantiates the class once.   Then no need to worry about generating compiler warnings if the class is instantiated more than once, since it cannot be.

As far as I know, there is no equivalent to static_assert that simply emits a warning, and the only way to emit compiler warnings (short of writing a compiler extension) is via the preprocessor, either #warning or #pragma message. You can't mix preprocessor directives and template metaprogramming conditionals, they just don't interact this way*.
If you really want to do something at compile-time, I would require that a specific symbol be defined in order to generate the code that instantiates more than one method. When this symbol is not defined, the class would behave like a singleton, but when it is defined, you would enable the code that allows more than one instance of your class to be instantiated, and that is when you can also emit a warning:
class Foo {
  Foo* getInstance();
#ifdef ALLOW_MULTIPLE_FOO
#warning "You are compiling in allow-multiple-foo mode. Please only do this if you know what you're doing"
  Foo* makeAnotherFoo();
#endif

private:
  Foo();
};

This makes Foo a singleton by default, but allows for people to explicitly opt-in to the rare "I need a second Foo" case.

*Note that, even if you could conditionally emit warnings from a metaprogram (ie, if there were a static_assert that only emitted a warning), you can't tell at compile-time whether multiple instances will be instantiated at runtime.
For example, this code may instantiate 0, 1 or 2 instances:
Foo* instance;
if (runtime_condition) {
  instance = Foo::makeFoo();
}

if (other_runtime_condition) {
  instance = Foo::makeAnotherFoo();
}

You might be able to enforce, at runtime, that runtime_condition and other_runtime_condition are mutually exclusive, but the compiler doesn't know this in the general case.

This is the direction I was aiming at with my original [wrong] comment. But here it is done right.
